# How can I change datefield in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem with DateField. How to do so that after clicking the button the date will change to the selected one?I set the date in admin panel. What am i doing wrong?

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
birth_date = models.DateField()
```

views.py

```
def profileView(request):
user = User.objects.get(username='szymon')
birth_date = user.student.birth_date
formatedDate = birth_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")


if request.method == "POST":
    j = request.POST['birth-date']
    j = user.student.birth_date



return render(request, 'home/profile.html', {'birth_date': formatedDate})
```

profile.html

```
<p>data urodzin: {{birth_date}}</p>
<form class="birth-form" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="usr"><b>Data urodzin: </b></label>
<input type="date" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" value='' name="birth-date" id="birth-date" required>
<button class="btn btn-light">Zmień</button>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1QUx.png

Answer (score 0):

you have to put bootstrap date time picker for this and dont forget to add jquery and bootstrap before adding this

in profile.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

add this script and also add

```
<script type='text/js'>
    $('.birth-date').datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        startDate: '-3d'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: but wait, where i should paste it?